# Redux and react-router proper setup

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

Im new to Redux.
Trying to setup it within a current project.

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import * as reducers from './store/reducers'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'

const store = createStore(combineReducers(reducers), composeWithDevTools(
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
))
```

Have a routing scheme with Provider in place:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Route path='/' component={App} onEnter={auth}>
        <Route path='/token' component={Token} />
        <Route path='/engagement' component={Engagement} />
        <Route path='/clients' component={Clients} />
      </Route>
    </Provider>
</Router>
```

And I have a basic container component in `<Clients />` component:

```
class Clients extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div className='any-css' >
        <Row>
          <ClientsSubMenuContainer someId={13} />
        </Row>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

that I'm trying to connect with store:

```
class ClientsSubMenuContainer extends Component {
  render () {
    return <ClientsSubMenu {...this.props} />
  }
}
// which props do we want to inject, given the global store state?
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ClientsSubMenuContainer)
```

and all I get currently is a warning:

> Uncaught Error: Could not find "store" in either the context or props
>   of "Connect(ClientsSubMenuContainer)". Either wrap the root component
>   in a , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to
>   "Connect(ClientsSubMenuContainer)".

**How to setup this correctly so all components (excluding or including login) will have access to store and all redux features?**

**Update** 1 day later
I just found the core of the problem, thanks to the community.
There was another piece of code in `index.js` that was added ruthlesly by one of the juniors against any gitFlow :) I didn't noticed it because was totally sure that master branch is save from any changes. 
This piece of code looked like that:

```
let router = (
   <Router history={browserHistory} onUpdate={onUpdate}>
     {Routes}
   </Router>
)
render(Routes, document.getElementById('app'))
```

so the final result was:

```
<Router history={browserHistory} onUpdate={onUpdate}>
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
     <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
      <Route path='/' component={App} onEnter={auth}>
        <Route path='/token' component={Token} />
        <Route path='/engagement' component={Engagement} />
        <Route path='/clients' component={Clients} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>       
</Router>
```

and router worked just fine. The only hint was redux warning, that disappeared after removing wrapping `<Router />`

Comment: Can you show your call to `createStore`? I'm guessing that could be the issue.

Comment: Sure, have to add this from the very beginning...

Comment: Try keeping `Router` inside the `Provider`. in routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try wrapping all component with provider.

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
      <Route path='/' component={App} onEnter={auth}>
        <Route path='/token' component={Token} />
        <Route path='/engagement' component={Engagement} />
        <Route path='/clients' component={Clients} />
      </Route>
   </Router>
</Provider>
```